# ViewController Crashing with Google Maps Navigation

Tags: ios, google-maps, navigation

I have a view controller named Colts and another view controller named fixtures which is only accessible via a button on the colts page. this did work fine. On the fixture page this has information for a cricket teams fixtures. with away matched having a button next to the match being able to link to google maps for navigation to said game.

to the fixture.h file i have added:

```
- (IBAction)oakley:(id)sender;
```

and to the fixture.m file:

```
- (IBAction)oakley:(id)sender {
CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { (51.292717), (-0.777315)};
CLLocationCoordinate2D end = { (51.241265), (-1.189302) };

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];

}
```

This should put in coordinates to Oakleys ground with a google maps pop ready to start navigating. I currently am having to presume this is correct as when i click the button to gain access to the fixtures page via the colts page the app just crashes. Without this code on the oakley button on the fixture view controller the link between the buttons worked perfectly and could see the fixtures, now with the code I cannot.

Does anyone know why the app crashes before even being able to access the fixture page? As this crashes i can't test if the oakley button and google maps pop up shows!

Comment: Could you provide more detail?  What is the exception message?  Which line does it on?  Have a read of http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @Paulw11 Firstly I have a number of other viewcontrollers on a tab bar to but they function perfectly. One has Google Maps on it showing a pin on a location but this isn't linked to the other viewcontrollers so shouldnt be a problem....   I think the error is "libc++abi.dylib: Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" I have this problem a few time but I don't see how this could affect what ive done recently, delete said code above and it works fine. Error in thread 1, not overly sure where to locate the error if im honest

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint?  The instructions are on the page I linked to.

Comment: @Paulw11 I haven't set any breakpoint personally. however there seems to be 3 in the program. of which one is in the viewcontroller im trying to open. (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibnameOrnil bundle:(NSbundle*)nibBundOrNil{..... etc ...which I have no idea why that's there, prerequisite code im guessing. Sorry for not being of much help but I have no idea whats going on

Comment: You need to set an exception breakpoint